# Blockchain is (fully?) synchronized, but lmdb size is 1 Gb

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, blockchain-size, blockchain-import, whonix

I'm just starting with Monero.
I'm using pre-installed Monero (XMR) Wallet on Whonix.

My settings are:

- Advanced mode
- Portable mode enabled
- Local node, with location of blockchain set to a separate partition (an external USB flash drive)

After a couple of hours of synchronization status changed to "Wallet is synchronized" and "Daemon is synchronized"("Daemon is synchronized" has a number in parentheses after it, though I'm not sure if it is safe to post it here).
[image: Synchronized status]

When I go to my flash drive - the size of "lmdb" folder (which, I understood, contains blockchain) is around 1.3 Gb, though my understanding is - current Monero blockchain should be more than 100 Gb.

My questions:

1. Is Monero blockchain synchronized to my flash drive or is it not? (If yes, why "lmdb" folder is so small?)
2. Should I [import blockchain manually](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html) instead?

Comment: Could you go to the `Settings` page -> `Log` tab, type `status`, and post the output here?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE, sure result is:
`... I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.1.2-release)
Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request:`

Searching for solution, I've found this https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12011/error-problem-fetching-info-rpc-request-when-running-monerod-as-service
Should I somehow reconfigure Monero (XMR) Wallet (mind you it came pre-installed and pre-configured on Whonix)?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE, Instead of `...` there is date and time, in the following format: [_date and time_] _date and time up to millisecond_

Comment: If you are using Whonix, can you please have a look at this comment? https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/qld9xm/operation_whonix_with_preinstalled_monero_wallet/hj2cslm/